# What kind of events are apt for a college-level MathFest?

Tags: soft-question

I want to get some ideas for events which can be organized for undergraduate students in a university. I have organized a math treasure-hunt and some problem-solving events in the past but I want to do something new this time.

I'm sorry if this question is too vague/doesn't suit the standard guidelines. Looking forward to some help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a college-level MathFest" (recreational activities between undergraduate presentations? activities for an end-of-the-year celebration?), but I would look into the possibility of inviting people from your community (or within a couple hours driving distance) who majored in math and who are working in areas that their math background has some relevance to their job tasks.

Comment: Its more like the latter. I want to put up some interesting/challenging competitions.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in looking at what was done by the students in a Math Capstone course of the host college for the most recent Iowa MAA Section meeting (October 2013; I was there). It was a game they called *Survivor X*, and you can find some things about it by googling ["Survivor X" Wartburg](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Survivor+X%22+Wartburg). I think the Math Capstone course was taught by Mariah Birgen (at [WartBurg College](http://www.wartburg.edu/mcsp/faculty.aspx)), but I'm not certain. However, I am sure that she could tell you more about it if you are interested.